# randomly replace random numbers of char in a string

Tags: java, random, replace

I'm new to Java and I need some help with my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class asdf {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int num1;
        String theWord;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string to rearrange");
        theWord = in.nextLine();
        int length = theWord.length();
        Random times=new Random();
        System.out.println("Length of String:"+length);
        char[] chars=theWord.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        int timez=times.nextInt();
        num1=generator.nextInt(length);
        char c=theWord.charAt(num1);
        String newWord=new String(chars);
        for(int i=0;i+=1;i<timez)
        {
            newWord=newWord.replace(c, '*');
        }
        System.out.println(newWord);
     }
}
```

So I was trying to rearrange the string and replace some of the chars with '*', but it didn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: First of all you need to swap `i+=1` and `i<timez` in your `for` loop

Comment: for(int i=0;i+=1;i<timez) is wrong , it should be   for(int i=0;i<timez;i+=1)

Comment: Check the `for` loop. It should be something like: `for(int i=0;i<timez;i++)`

Comment: I changed them around, now it works but often takes around 20 seconds to process, is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class asdf {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int num1;
    String theWord;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string to rearrange");
    theWord = in.nextLine();
    int length = theWord.length();
    Random times=new Random();
    System.out.println("Length of String:"+length);
    char[] chars=theWord.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    int timez=times.nextInt();
    num1=generator.nextInt(length);
    char c=theWord.charAt(num1);
    String newWord=new String(chars);
    for(int i=0;i<timez;i++) {
        newWord=newWord.replace(c, '*');
    }
    System.out.println(newWord);
    }
 }
```

Ideone example: http://ideone.com/PjfAor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `for` loop. You should change the loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < timez; i++)
```

If you are interested, here is one other cleaner way of achieving what you are trying to achieve:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] input = in.nextLine().toCharArray();

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        int leftIndex = rand.nextInt(input.length - 1);
        int rightIndex = rand.nextInt(input.length - 1);

        if (leftIndex == rightIndex)
            continue;

        char buffer = input[leftIndex];
        input[leftIndex] = input[rightIndex];
        input[rightIndex] = buffer;
    }

    System.out.println(input);
    in.close();
}
```

**Input:**

```
mango
```

**Output:**

```
ngamo
```